# Translation in template with placeholders

Tags: django

in my .po file i have

> msgid "This string will have %s inside."

How can i translate this in template?

I've tried:

> {% blocktrans %}This string will have {{ value }} inside.{% endblocktrans %}

and

> {% blocktrans with value as value%}This string will have {{ value }} inside.{% endblocktrans %}

Neither works for me

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#how-to-specify-translation-strings), the strings should use Python's standard named-string interpolation syntax.

So `{% blocktrans %}This string will have {{ value }} inside.{% endblocktrans %}` will use the translation string `"This string will have %(value)s inside."`.